# What font is used in this Savoy Take Away sign?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

Can anyone name the font used in the three images below? I know they are from poor angles but hopefully someone can name it.

Also if someone with more than 10 rep points could repost them as pictures, that would be a big help. I have a third image but I cant post it for the same reason.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Logo Side 1]
[image: Logo Side 2]
[image: Logo Side 3]

I have found Dragon EF that seems quite close, but am still open to suggestions. Here is my attempt, but the K and W don't quite measure up:

[image: My attempt]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Friz Quadrata Bold](http://www.fonts.com/findfonts/detail.htm?productid=215336).

Comment: Good suggestion. That resolves the W and V problem, but the T looks off in that.

Comment: That's the angle from which the photographs were done that's fooling you. Andrew is correct.

Comment: So he is. Tick awarded.